# Issues with Animation on Scroll, someone has an advice?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, scroll

I am trying to make an on scroll animation combined with the css snap on scroll.

what I want to do is to snap to the next section with just a scroll but also animate the section with the AOS library. but the AOS library ain't working while combined with the css snap method.

Here is the code I have, anyone has an idea how to make this one work?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ives-4ikb3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this sort of animation?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: grey;
}
.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: green;
  width: 0%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  Scroll Indicator - Scroll Down to See The Effect
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
</div>

<script>
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```